# Kafka connector is not reading a mongodb collection

Tags: mongodb, apache-kafka, debezium

Using debezium mongo connector, I am pushing data out of mongodb to kafka. I have 4 collections: transactions, wallets, cards and users.

Before launching kafka-connector, I created a topic "mongo_conn.digi.users". and when i re-launch it Kafka-connector created "mongo_conn.digi.cards" and "mongo_conn.digi.transactions" topic on it's own and got data pushed to them. However, it did not create a topic for wallets and did not push data to "mongo_conn.digi.users".

So, I deleted "mongo_conn.digi.users" and re-launched connector. As expected, "mongo_conn.digi.users" was recreated by kafka-connector but nothing has been pushed too. also no topic was created for wallets collection same issue.

I am trying to find a reason on why connector did not create any topic for wallets topic & why kafka-connector is not pushing any data for users topic 
this is my connector output

Comment: Please delete all topics from kafka. Btw, wallets sound like an important collection in your database. Does it require any special permission? What is your connector configuration ? Have you verified whether the version of mongodb is compatible with connector or not?

Comment: somehow i can't locate zkCli, did the name change ? i have to make sure they got deleted through the zookeeper cli

Comment: The latest version of Kafka stores limited amount of information on zookeeper. I would not recommend messing with zookeeper. just make sure that zookeeper is up all the time.

Comment: Alright so in order to delete the topics i have to add delete.topic.enable=true in my /etc/kafka/server.properties and then hit the command that's it ? the problem is that i did that in the first place and it's no longer showing the the topic list but then again i wanted to deleted this time without adding delete.topic.enable=true in my /etc/kafka/server.properties it was marked for delete and when i started the servers backup it's not shown in my topic lists, so i guess it's still in there but i can't see it with kafka-topics --list --zookeeper localhost:2181

Comment: I know working with kafka can be tricky. But kafka document is the source of truth. Now, when you run list_topics command and if it does not enlist your topic then kafka has deleted your topic or will delete it later.

Comment: yes indeed i just found out that the in the current version you don't need to add delete.topic.enable=true , so yes i've deleted all my kafka topics and and started again the pipeline and all i have now is transactions and cards

Comment: can the problem be cause i've changed the heap size allocation for kafka to 300m ?

Comment: It is very easy to get tangled with kafka configuration. I would recommend you to keep default parameters and only update connector related configuration.